# Finding birth/baptism record for Don ancestor who resided in Arad in Transylvania before World War I?

Tags: birth-records, baptism-records, 1900s-decade, hungary

My late father in law was born in Arad around 1905-1906. His last name was Don. This is not a Hungarian name, although he was. I believe it is the name of a river in Russia. I am trying to do genealogy on my husband's side of the family.

I believe my father in law had a brother, John and a sister, Clara.  Neither of them were living when he came to the states after world war I.

I have no information on his parents.

How would I find a baptism/birth record for him that might name one or both of his parents?

Comment: Hi! and welcome to Genealogy & Family History SE. Please, expand more on what you already know about your father-in-law - when did he arrive in the USA, where did he settle, what religion, which nationality or ethnicity are on his census entries. What do his marriage and death records or obituary say about his family? If you haven't done the US research, it will be very difficult to jump to Europe. [Arad was a multi-cultural region, with Hungarian, Romanians, Germans, Serbs and other minorities]

Comment: Although very rare, Don does occur as a Hungarian surname; it's an unmarked patronymic based on a short form of Donát (Donatus). (Yes, it's also the name of a river in Russia, but this sort of coincidence is to be expected for any simple and short combination of common sounds.)

Comment: It sounds contradictory, but in general, it's best to ignore names when doing genealogy. You can't ignore them completely, of course, since they're the only way to keep track of people, but the origins, language, or other specifics of the name are only peripherally relevant to the task of identifying people and their relationships.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! Please take the [tour] and look at the material in the [help] to see more about how the site works. Your question as written may not attract good answers because if you ask for "any information" that is too vague and broad.  You haven't told us much about your research effort or how you know what you know. Adding these things and letting us know more specifically what you need help with with help us give you better answers.

Comment: To try and progress this question I am going to narrow its scope to be looking for a birth/baptism record for your late father-in-law.  In order to look for that it would be helpful to know his full name and any source that you have mentioning his birthplace and year.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question that enables you to revise your question with additional details like that.

Comment: Another question that you could ask, as a New Question, is where to find an immigration record for him.  For that it would be helpful to include his full name, and any details you might know about the year and country of his immigration.